# How to automatically add _blank to anchor links in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, anchor

Is it possible to for a script to automatically add **target="_blank"** to anchor links in Ruby on Rails.

For example, when I add a link in a blog I'd like it to automatically have **_blank** on every link so the link opens in a new window.

Is this possible with Javascript or Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using JavaScript:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    if (!/^#/.test($(this).attr('href'))) {
        window.open(this.href, '_blank');
        return false;
    }
});
```

This code will open all the anchors with the `target` attribute set to `_blank`.

Comment: But wouldn't that be for only one of the anchors? I'm looking for it to be added to every link in a blog post for example.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. I updated my answer adding a JavaScript way to do it. :)

Comment: I would suggest you avoid explicit binds like above (they would not work for any new content pulled down w/AJAX etc.) but use `delegate` instead. As an extra bonus, you could modify the selector to only open *external* links in a new tab/window `$("a:not([href*='mydomain.com'])")`

Comment: @o.v. Thanks for the suggestion. Feel free to edit my answer to reflect that. -- Jamie: Can you accept my answer please?